# what is list definition in moss

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

what is list definition in moss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of List Definition as a Blueprint or template of a list using which you can create instances of list. For example, MOSS comes with out of the box list definitions like Announcements, Tasks etc. You can create a list using those list definitions and the list instances could be: "Department Announcements", "Team Announcements" etc.

At a very high level, a List Definition contains: Name of the list, template name as it appears in Sharepoint UI, parent list type from which it is deriving, the content types and fields which belong to the list, default and custom views of the list etc.

More information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023(v=office.12).aspx

If you are new to MOSS, creating a list definition is fairly advanced topic and it involves learning many more things than List Definition itself.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413946.aspx):

> **SharePoint list.** A structure of items or rows and columns or fields that contain data provided by SharePoint similar to a database table. The SharePoint object model uses the class SPList to represent a SharePoint list.

Further explained here:

> **[What is a SharePoint list](http://www.understandingsharepoint.com/justask/what-is-a-sharepoint-list)**

Comment: ok what is the definition for "List Dedinition" and how to create custom List definition

Comment: From 0xA3's link... A List Definition is the schema for a list (defined using XML). See Rahul's answer for creating one.

Comment: the user is asking about List Difinition and not the List itself.